# ccny_rgbd normal behavior?

Tags: ros, openni, ccny-rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey! hope someone can help me here, I just wanted to make sure that this is normal behavior because I am getting some WARNINGS

**roslaunch ccny_openni_launch openni.launch publish_cloud:=true**

throws these warnings

```
[ WARN] [1365750031.849575558]: [rgb_0000000000000000] does not match name rgb in file /home/fersarr/catkin_ws/src/ccny_rgbd/ccny_rgbd_tools/ccny_rgbd/data/calibration_openni_default/rgb.yml
[ WARN] [1365750031.851442142]: [depth_0000000000000000] does not match name depth in file /home/fersarr/catkin_ws/src/ccny_rgbd/ccny_rgbd_tools/ccny_rgbd/data/calibration_openni_default/depth.yml
```

heres the full output

```
fersarr@fersarrPC:~$ roslaunch ccny_openni_launch openni.launch publish_cloud:=true
... logging to /home/fersarr/.ros/log/a76d8176-a33e-11e2-83b6-a417313a9d99/roslaunch-fersarrPC-2706.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server fersarrPC:52985/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /openni_driver/depth_camera_info_url
 * /openni_driver/depth_frame_id
 * /openni_driver/depth_mode
 * /openni_driver/device_id
 * /openni_driver/image_mode
 * /openni_driver/rgb_camera_info_url
 * /openni_driver/rgb_frame_id
 * /rgbd_image_proc/calib_path
 * /rgbd_image_proc/publish_cloud
 * /rgbd_image_proc/scale
 * /rgbd_image_proc/unwarp
 * /rgbd_image_proc/verbose
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /
    camera_rgb_frame_tf (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_rgb_optical_frame_tf (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
    openni_driver (nodelet/nodelet)
    rgbd_image_proc (nodelet/nodelet)
    rgbd_manager (nodelet/nodelet)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [2720]
ROS_MASTER_URI=localhost:11311

setting /run_id to a76d8176-a33e-11e2-83b6-a417313a9d99
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [2733]
started core service [/rosout]
process[rgbd_manager-2]: started with pid [2745]
process[openni_driver-3]: started with pid [2746]
[ INFO] [1365750027.705988566]: Loading nodelet /openni_driver of type openni_camera/driver to manager rgbd_manager with the following remappings:
[ INFO] [1365750027.706151486]: /depth -> /camera/depth
[ INFO] [1365750027.706185220]: /ir -> /camera/ir
[ INFO] [1365750027.706232955]: /rgb -> /camera/rgb
[ INFO] [1365750027.708404449]: waitForService: Service [/rgbd_manager/load_nodelet] has not been advertised, waiting...
process[debayer-4]: started with pid [2767]
process[rgbd_image_proc-5]: started with pid [2794]
process[camera_rgb_frame_tf-6]: started with pid [2822]
[ INFO] [1365750028.104817306]: Initializing nodelet with 8 worker threads.
[ INFO] [1365750028.124780365]: waitForService: Service [/rgbd_manager/load_nodelet] is now available.
process[camera_rgb_optical_frame_tf-7]: started with pid [2882]
[ INFO] [1365750028.705934929]: Initializing RGBD Image Proc Nodelet
[ INFO] [1365750028.853396826]: Reading camera calibration files...
[ INFO] [1365750029.359387411]: Resampling scale set to 1.00
[ INFO] [1365750031.732731887]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1365750031.732938190]: 1. device on bus 003:09 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id '0000000000000000'
[ INFO] [1365750031.734548570]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1365750031.783989876]: Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 3:9 with serial number '0000000000000000'
[ INFO] [1365750031.835639404]: rgb_frame_id = '/camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1365750031.835786170]: depth_frame_id = '/camera_depth_optical_frame' 
[ WARN] [1365750031.849575558]: [rgb_0000000000000000] does not match name rgb in file /home/fersarr/catkin_ws/src/ccny_rgbd/ccny_rgbd_tools/ccny_rgbd/data/calibration_openni_default/rgb.yml
[ WARN] [1365750031.851442142]: [depth_0000000000000000] does not match name depth in file /home/fersarr/catkin_ws/src/ccny_rgbd/ccny_rgbd_tools/ccny_rgbd/data/calibration_openni_default/depth.yml
[ INFO] [1365750036.501789369]: Initializing
[ INFO] [1365750036.502020279]: Initializing rectification maps
```

And when running the following command I get this lines continously

**roslaunch ccny_rgbd vo+mapping.launch**

```
[ INFO] [1365751163.416996164]: [VO 31875] Fr: 0.0 GFT[400][387]: 11.2 ICPProbModel[5999]  2.8 TOTAL 14.2

[ INFO] [1365751163.454457740]: [VO 31876] Fr: 0.0 GFT[400][382]: 11.2 ICPProbModel[5999]  2.7 TOTAL 14.1

[ INFO] [1365751163.489547112]: [VO 31877] Fr: 0.0 GFT[400][382]: 14.4 ICPProbModel[5999]  3.2 TOTAL 17.7

[ INFO] [1365751163.521905724]: [VO 31878] Fr: 0.0 GFT[400][384]: 10.8 ICPProbModel[5999]  2.5 TOTAL 13.4

[ INFO] [1365751163.554707482]: [VO 31879] Fr: 0.0 GFT[400][388]: 12.8 ICPProbModel[5999]  3.4 TOTAL 16.4

[ INFO] [1365751163.587315825]: [VO 31880] Fr: 0.0 GFT[400][386]: 17.7 ICPProbModel[5999]  2.7 TOTAL 20.6

[ INFO] [1365751163.622854766]: [VO 31881] Fr: 0.0 GFT[400][384]: 14.3 ICPProbModel[5999]  3.1 TOTAL 17.5

[ INFO] [1365751163.656007181]: [VO 31882] Fr: 0.0 GFT[400][387]: 16.1 ICPProbModel[5999]  2.5 TOTAL 18.7

[ INFO] [1365751163.686356980]: [VO 31883] Fr: 0.0 GFT[400][388]: 14.7 ICPProbModel[5999]  2.6 TOTAL 17.4

[ INFO] [1365751163.723552755]: [VO 31884] Fr: 0.0 GFT[400][386]: 13.7 ICPProbModel[5999]  5.5 TOTAL 19.3

[ INFO] [1365751163.754546877]: [VO 31885] Fr: 0.0 GFT[400][383]: 12.3 ICPProbModel[5999]  2.5 TOTAL 14.9

[ INFO] [1365751163.787912310]: [VO 31886] Fr: 0.0 GFT[400][384]: 15.7 ICPProbModel[5999]  2.8 TOTAL 18.7

[ INFO] [1365751163.823260745]: [VO 31887] Fr: 0.0 GFT[400][384]: 12.4 ICPProbModel[5999]  2.8 TOTAL 15.3

[ INFO] [1365751163.853866664]: [VO 31888] Fr: 0.0 GFT[400][384]: 12.8 ICPProbModel[5999]  2.6 TOTAL 15.6

[ INFO] [1365751163.885874227]: [VO 31889] Fr: 0.0 GFT[400][388]: 13.8 ICPProbModel[5999]  3.2 TOTAL 17.2

^C[ INFO] [1365751163.923674804]: [VO 31890] Fr: 0.0 GFT[400][382]: 14.5 ICPProbModel[5999]  2.9 TOTAL 17.6
```

and, finally rviz gives me some WARNINGS

```
fersarr@fersarrPC:~$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1365750127.315568690]: rviz version 1.9.28
[ INFO] [1365750127.315762567]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1365750128.008996902]: OpenGl version: 3.0 (GLSL 1.3).
[ WARN] [1365750399.442449910]: Messages of type 1 arrived closer (0.035933361) than the lower bound you provided (0.500000000) (will print only once)
[ WARN] [1365750410.364681460]: Messages of type 1 arrived closer (0.035960454) than the lower bound you provided (0.500000000) (will print only once)
[ WARN] [1365750413.862328396]: Messages of type 1 arrived closer (0.031704339) than the lower bound you provided (0.500000000) (will print only once)
[ WARN] [1365750428.672357494]: MessageFilter [target=/odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.rviz.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
[ WARN] [1365750488.681948257]: MessageFilter [target=/odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.rviz.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
[ WARN] [1365750548.692350803]: MessageFilter [target=/odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.rviz.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60530/ccny_rgbd-normal-behavior?/) by [fersarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3210/fersarr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The output of

```
roslaunch ccny_rgbd vo+mapping.launch
```

points that ccny_rgbd is receiving the images and processing them correctly.

As for the warning:

```
[ WARN] [1365750031.849575558]: [rgb_0000000000000000] does not match name rgb in file /home/fersarr/catkin_ws/src/ccny_rgbd/ccny_rgbd_tools/ccny_rgbd/data/calibration_openni_default/rgb.yml
```

It appears that the config files I have provided don't match your camera name - I'm not sure what to make of that. I'm also not sure if it's actually an issue. Perhaps you could try launch ccny_rgbd with the default OpenNI launch files, bypassing the custom rgbd_image_proc pipeline. The`vo+mapping.launch` file has a note regarding how to remap topics if you're doing that.

The rviz warning probably have to do with setting the fixed_frame incorrectly (it needs to be set to `odom`). I have updated ccny_rgbd with a groovy .rviz config file to make it easier.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1